# Mat-autocomplete - How to access selected option?

Tags: angular

I know that `[value]` stores the selected Object (Offer in my case). According to materials documentation, `optionSelected` emits an event. I tried `[optionSelected] = "fooFn"` but it doesn't exist. I just want to access the Offer object. Thanks!

offer-search.component.html:

```
  <h5 #offerP>option - autoComplete</h5>
  <mat-form-field id="form-field">
    <input type="text" matInput [formControl]="myControl" [matAutocomplete]="auto">
    <mat-autocomplete #auto="matAutocomplete" [displayWith]="displayFn">
      <mat-option *ngFor="let option of filteredOptions$ | async" [value]="option">
        {{ option.foodItem.name }}
    </mat-option>
  </mat-autocomplete>
  </mat-form-field>
```

Comment: I am trying to fill in multiple input fields such that each field is  corresponding to the selected Offer object's property but i don't know how to access the object

Answer (score 154, accepted):

You can use it like :

```
<mat-autocomplete #auto="matAutocomplete" (optionSelected)='getPosts($event.option.value)'>
```

**[WORKING DEMO](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-mat-autocomp-dependent)**

Comment: Works! I guess I didn't know where to find the `.option.value` syntax even though it makes sense. I wonder what other information I can get from `$events` payload?

Comment: @CCSJ you can find the API info (specifically for `MatAutocompleteSelectedEvent`) right here https://material.angular.io/components/autocomplete/api

Comment: Is there a way we can stop the default autocomplete behavior of optionSelected event? Currently, selecting the option is overriding the complete text on the input. I want to append the selected text, not override it.

Comment: @RahulMunjal: See this one is perfect example as per your requirement.- Angular Material Chip https://material.angular.io/components/chips/overview . Please go through this.

Answer (score 25):

It can be done in two ways

1. Using `onSelectionChange` which emits `MatOptionSelectionChange` from `mat-option`

```
<mat-autocomplete #auto="matAutocomplete">
    <mat-option
      *ngFor="let option of options"
      [value]="option"
      (onSelectionChange)="updateMySelection($event)"
    >
      {{ option }}
    </mat-option>
</mat-autocomplete>
```

2. Using `optionSelected` which emits `MatAutocompleteSelectedEvent` from `mat-autocomplete`

```
<mat-autocomplete 
  #auto="matAutocomplete"
  (optionSelected)="updateMySelection($event)">
    <mat-option
      *ngFor="let option of options"
      [value]="option"
    >
      {{ option }}
    </mat-option>
</mat-autocomplete>
```

Comment: Is there any performance difference? How do I judge which one to choose between the two?

Comment: I am not sure, but I appears that there is not much except the event type is different

Comment: Option 1 is really useful when auto complete isn't only a string and we need the etire model to fill other fields, for example.

Answer (score 6):

```
 <mat-form-field floatLabel="always">
            <mat-label>UTBMS Activity Codes</mat-label>
            <input type="text" placeholder="Activity Codes"  [(ngModel)]="activityCode"  aria-label="Number" matInput [formControl]="utbmsActivityCodesControl"
              [matAutocomplete]="autoActivityCodes">
            <mat-autocomplete autoActiveFirstOption #autoActivityCodes="matAutocomplete">
              <mat-option *ngFor="let option of utbmsActivityCodes | async" (onSelectionChange)="setBillingActivity(option)"  [value]="option.code">
                {{option.name}}
              </mat-option>
            </mat-autocomplete>
          </mat-form-field>
```

```
setBillingActivity(object){
    this.actionData.libraryContent.billingActivityId=object.activityId;
  }
```

Answer (score 0):

```
// html
 
<h5 #offerP>option - autoComplete</h5>
  <mat-form-field id="form-field">
    <input type="text" matInput [formControl]="myControl" [matAutocomplete]="auto">
    <mat-autocomplete auto="matAutocomplete" [displayWith]="displayFn" (optionSelected)="populateForm($event);>
      <mat-option *ngFor="let option of filteredOptions$ | async" [value]="option">
        {{ option.foodItem.name }}
    </mat-option>
  </mat-autocomplete>
  </mat-form-field>

// TS

populateForm(event: MatAutocompleteSelectedEvent) {
    console.log(event.option.value);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately (optionSelected) did not work for me, I used (onSelectionChange), here is a thing onSelectionChange will throws two events simultaneously one for selection another for deselection, hence last value comes out to be previously selected value. So, I did the following:

```
<h5 #offerP>option - autoComplete</h5>
  <mat-form-field id="form-field">
    <input type="text" matInput [formControl]="myControl" [matAutocomplete]="auto">
    <mat-autocomplete auto="matAutocomplete" [displayWith]="displayFn" (onSelectionChange)="populateForm($event);>
      <mat-option *ngFor="let option of filteredOptions$ | async" [value]="option">
        {{ option.foodItem.name }}
    </mat-option>
  </mat-autocomplete>
  </mat-form-field>

// TS

populateForm(event: MatAutocompleteSelectedEvent) {
   if(event.source["_selected"] === true){
      //your next set of action goes here
    }
}
```