# Angular issue with array and observable to html

Tags: javascript, html, angular

I am having an issue with appending an array to a table ;
I am hoping to have the table be added to by the user adding a ticker.
The issue is related to the html side I believe. The goal is to append the html table and have 
it display to the user.I hope that there is a reasonable solution to this problem as it has been plaguing me for quite some time.

```
    import { Component, OnInit } from '@angular/core';
    import { Observable } from 'rxjs/Observable';
    import { AuthService } from './../auth/auth.service';
    import { FinancialNewsInterface } from '../FinancialNewsInterface';
    import { map, startWith } from 'rxjs/operators';
    import { FormControl } from '@angular/forms';
    import { NewsService } from '../news.service';
    import { PortfolioConstruction } from '../portfolio.service';
    import { PortfolioInterface } from '../PortfolioInterface';
    import { FinancialPricingInterface } from '../FinancialPricingInterface';
    import { PricingDataService } from '../pricing.service';

    @Component({
      selector: 'app-portfolios',
      templateUrl: './portfolios.component.html',
      styleUrls: ['./portfolios.component.css']
    })

    export class PortfoliosComponent implements OnInit {
     constructor(private portfoliosData : PortfolioConstruction,
      private authService: AuthService, private newsData : NewsService,
      private pricingData : PricingDataService) { }

      isLoggedIn$: Observable<boolean>;  
      ticker : string;
      post : PortfolioInterface[];
      postNews : FinancialNewsInterface[];
      myControl = new FormControl();
      filteredOptions: Observable<string[]>;
      option : PortfolioInterface[]; 
      postChart : FinancialPricingInterface[];



      options: string[] = [
    "ABT","ABBV","ABMD","ACN","ATVI","ADBE","AMD",
    "AAP","AES","AMG","AFL","A","APD","AKAM","ALK",
    "ALB","ARE","ALXN","ALGN","ALLE","AGN","ADS","LNT",
    "ALL","GOOGL","GOOG","MO","AMZN","AMCR","AEE","AAL","AEP",
    "AXP","AIG","AMT","AWK","AMP","ABC","AME","AMGN","APH","ADI",
    "FTV","FBHS","FOXA","FOX","BEN","FCX","GPS","GRMN","IT","GD","GE",
    "GIS","GM","GPC","GILD","GL","GPN","GS","GWW","HAL","HBI","HOG",
    "HIG","HAS","HCA","HCP","HP","HSIC","HSY","HES","HPE","HLT","HFC"
      ];


      ngOnInit() {  
        this.isLoggedIn$ = this.authService.isLoggedIn;

        this.pricingData.getPrices("SPY").subscribe(postChart => {
          this.postChart  = postChart;
        })

        this.portfoliosData.getPortfolios("SPY",["TLT","AAPL"]).subscribe(post => {
          this.post  = post;
        })

         this.newsData.getNews("SPY").subscribe(postNews => {
            this.postNews  = postNews;  })

            this.filteredOptions = this.myControl.valueChanges
            .pipe(startWith(''), map(value => this._filter(value)));

        }

        public _filter(value: string): string[] {
          const filterValue = value.toLowerCase();

          return this.options.filter(option => 
            option.toLowerCase().indexOf(filterValue) === 0);
        }

        public updatePortfolio(option){

          this.portfoliosData.getPortfolios("SPY",["TLT","AAPL"].unshift(option)
          ).subscribe(post => {
            this.post  = post;
          })

           this.newsData.getNews(option).subscribe(postNews => {
              this.postNews  = postNews; 
            })

            this.pricingData.getPrices(option).subscribe(postChart => {
              this.postChart  = postChart;
            })

        }  

    }
```

template:

```
   <div class = "row">
      <div class="col-lg-7">
        <h3>Portfolio Selection Page</h3>

        <igx-financial-chart [dataSource]=postChart width="750px" height="750px" brushes="Green, Blue" outlines="Green, Blue"
          negativeBrushes="Red" negativeOutlines="Red" thickness="1">
        </igx-financial-chart>

        <form class="example-form">
          <mat-form-field class="example-full-width">
            <label>Click here to input your Ticker:</label>
            <input type="text" aria-label="Number" matInput [formControl]="myControl" [matAutocomplete]="auto">
            <mat-autocomplete autoActiveFirstOption #auto="matAutocomplete">
              <mat-option *ngFor="let option of filteredOptions | async" [(value)]="option"
                (onSelectionChange)=updatePortfolio(option)>
                {{option}}
              </mat-option>
            </mat-autocomplete>
          </mat-form-field>
        </form>

        <div class="card" *ngFor="let post of postNews.data">
          <div class="card-body">
            <h3>{{ post.title }}</h3>
            <p>{{ post.text }}</p>
            <img src={{post.image_url}} alt="">
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>

      <!-------- Portfolio Table Functionality -------->
      <div class="col-lg-5">
          <div class="alert alert-info"><b>Current Portfolio </b></div>
          <div class="table-responsive">
            <table class="table">
              <thead>
                <tr>
                  <th>Stock</th>
                  <th>Previous Close</th>
                  <th>Latest Price</th>
                  <th>Percent Change</th>
                </tr>
              </thead>
              <tbody>
                <tr *ngFor="let post of post">
                  <td>{{post.code}}</td>
                  <td>{{post.previousClose}}</td>
                  <td>{{post.close}}</td>
                  <td>{{post.change_p}}</td>
                </tr>
              </tbody>
            </table>
          </div>
        </div>
```

Comment: The issue I believe is in the update portfolio section.

Comment: Can you please create a minimal verifiable [stackblitz](https://stackblitz.com/fork/angular) example replicating your issue to work with?

Comment: unfortunately i am not familiar with stackblitz...

Comment: this.portfoliosData.getPortfolios("SPY",["TLT","AAPL"].unshift(option)
          ).subscribe(post => {
            this.post  = post;
          })

Comment: I replace with this and got close to the target goal but the issue is now only one item is appended. public updatePortfolio( option){
      this.portfoliosData.getPortfolios("SPY",
      ["TLT","AAPL"].concat(option)).subscribe(post => {
        this.post  = post;
      })

Comment: Please try using optionselected event on mat-autocomplete. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48603673/mat-autocomplete-how-to-access-selected-option/48606100

Comment: What is the purpose of ["TLT","AAPL"].concat(option) or ["TLT","AAPL"].unshift(option) ? Because only one option is selected from auto completed and it is added to ["TLT","AAPL"] always, which does not contain previous selected values. May be you should try retaining the selected values in an array.